# not able to add this js code to styling my material design chips

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

how to add this code to react js.when i added it as a function it shows that $ is not defined.moreover i tried various methods but was not successful in adding this code

```
$(function () {
    $('.chips__choice .chip').on("click", function () {
        $('.chips__choice .chip').removeClass('chip--active');
        $(this).addClass("chip--active");
    });
    $('.chips__filter .chip').on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("chip--active");
    });
});
```

it is showing $ is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Better to avoid using Jquery in React app, but if it is necessary then you can do this:

1. `npm install jquery` in terminal
2. `import $ from 'jquery'` in the component where paste your code

Comment: can you modify this jquery code to Javascript code @Evgenii